# Adding vector image to Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: java, android, image, google-maps, vector

**How do I add an image to my Google map precisely according to more than one LatLng value?**

Here is my code:

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;

...

googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MainActivity)).getMap();

...
```

For example, I have the blueprint image of a car park. I would like to add this image to my Google map.Research seems to recommend converting the image into a vector graphic; however the next part is where I am confused.

However the purpose relates to navigation, therefore the image placement must be accurate. The car park is rectangularly-shaped and thus has four corners. Each corner has had its respective coordinates collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay).

V2 API doesn't allow you to add vector graphics to the map (yet).